# Iterate over Arraylist<String[]>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iterator

I have an ArrayList full with String arrays that I can't figure out how to loop through. Iterators are new to me and even though I have used them in the past, I'm not sure what to do here.

```
Iterator<String[]> iterator = list.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String trip = "Till: " + iterator.next(0) + " | Från: " + list.get(4) + " | Kostar: " + list.get(1) +"kr | Avgår: " + list.get(2) + " | Ankomst Tid: " + list.get(3) + " | Antal bokningar: " + list.get(4);
```

This is some experimenting I am doing. I though that iterator.next() would return the StringArray on the current row so I have tried for example iterator.next(0). As I understand list.get(x) only gives me the row.

In the code above, I want every rows String Array at a certain index.
Something like this:

```
for each row
 system.out.println(String[2] +String[5]);
```

Comment: There is a subtle difference in that the author is trying to determine how to use the Array value inside the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you have a list of arrays, not a list of Strings.

```
List<String[]> list = //some data
for (String[] array : list){
    System.out.println(array[3] + ":" + array[5]);
}
```

If you want to iterate over each string you will have to iterate twice.

```
List<String[]> list = //some data
for (String[] array : list){
    for (String s : array){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

The above is shorthand for using an iterator.

```
List<String[]> list = //some data
Iterator<String[]> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    String[] array = itr.next(); // You were just missing saving the value for reuse
    System.out.println(array[3] + ":" + array[5]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having to worry about iterators in your code:

```
List<String[]> test = new ArrayList<>();
for(String[] array : test) {
    //Iterate over inner array:
    for(String s : array) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    //or access directly
    System.out.println(array[0]);
}
```

Comment: Pipped to the post by 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterator<String[]> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String[] row = iterator.next();
    //Do stuff with row
}
```

If you're using a list, you can also use a for loop:

```
for(String[] row : list) {
    //Do stuff with row
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Each item in the ArrayList is a String[], so iterator.next() returns a String[].  Once you have that String array, you can access it like any other array with array index notation. `item[0]` is the first item in the array, `item.length` tells you how many items are in the array.

Where you're calling `list.get(4)` will also return an array of strings, which almost certainly isn't what you want in the output.